# Create a list numbered 1 a), b), c), 2 a), b), etc

Tags: lists, enumerate

I want to create a list like this:

```
1 (a) first item  
  (b) second item  

2 (a) third item  
  (b) fourth item  

3 (a) fifth item  
  (b) sixth item
```

and so on.
Is there any way I can do it?

Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I found my answer by trying enumerate in the \item

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing you need to change is to issue the instruction

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}
```

in order to get rid of the period (aka full stop) that's placed after the level-1 numerals.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi} % default is "\theenumi."
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{enumerate}
\item first item  
\item second item  
\end{enumerate}

\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item third item  
\item fourth item  
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```